# Найти равные значения в массиве

Tags: php

Как сократить код на php в проверке значений в массиве

```
<?
$deget = array();

$deget[0] = $_GET['input-0'];

$deget[1] = $_GET['input-1'];

$deget[2] = $_GET['input-2'];

$deget[3] = $_GET['input-3'];
$deget[4] = $_GET['input-4'];

$deget[5] = $_GET['input-5'];
$deget[6] = $_GET['input-6'];
$deget[7] = $_GET['input-7'];
$deget[8] = $_GET['input-8'];


$deget[9] = $_GET['input-9'];
$deget[10] = $_GET['input-10'];
$deget[11] = $_GET['input-11'];
$deget[12] = $_GET['input-12'];
$deget[13] = $_GET['input-13'];
$deget[14] = $_GET['input-14'];
$deget[15] = $_GET['input-15'];
$deget[16] = $_GET['input-16'];
$deget[17] = $_GET['input-17'];
$deget[18] = $_GET['input-18'];
$deget[19] = $_GET['input-19'];
$deget[20] = $_GET['input-20'];
$deget[21] = $_GET['input-21'];
$deget[22] = $_GET['input-22'];
$deget[23] = $_GET['input-23'];
$deget[24] = $_GET['input-24'];
$deget[25] = $_GET['input-25'];


if (($deget[1] == $deget[2]) or ($deget[1] == $deget[3]) or ($deget[1] == $deget[4]) ... or ($deget[25] == $deget[24]))
    
?>
```

Comment: простите, это реальный кусок кода, в котором вручную проверены все пары 25х25 ?

Comment: нет, это пример кода никто 625 проверок не писал)

Answer (score 0):

1. Вместо извращения в виде `input-0`/`input-1`/`input-2`...`input-N`  на форме надо сделать инпуты с именем `input[]` тогда все значения полетят в один массив с именем `input` и лежать будет по единственному ключу `$_GET['input']`
2. Далее с этим работать очень просто:

   - Применить **[array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php)**  для подсчёта дубликатов в массиве.
   - Пробежаться по этому массиву циклом `foreach` и если хотя бы одно значение будет больше 1, значит дубликаты имеются

Answer (score 0):

Заполнение массива можно сократить с помощью простого цикла.
А найти повторы можно так.
`array_unique()` - создаст массив с уникальными элементами из массива.
Если кол-во уникальных меньше, чем кол-во всех элементов, то значит, что есть дубликаты

```js
<?php

$deget = [];

for($i=0; $i<=25; $i++) {
    $deget[$i] = $_GET["input-$i"];
}

if(count(array_unique($deget)) < count($deget)) {
    // Array has dublicates
}
```

Comment: <?php

$deget = [];

for($i=0; $i<=25; $i++) {
    $deget[$i] = $_GET["input-$i"];
}

if(count(array_unique($deget)) < count($deget)) {
 
echo "yes";

} else {
 echo "no";
}

при попытке проверить, не важно при каком либо значении всегда идет вывод yes

Comment: Проверил на таком массиве - `[123,123,321]` - срабатывает первое условие. А если убрать значение `321`, то оно не срабатывает. ТО есть работает правильно. Проверьте данные, которые у вас в массиве `$deget`